# Node.js Promise without returning it

Tags: node.js, promise, bluebird

I have a use case to resolve a Promise without returning it. Catching for errors internally, but don't want the caller to wait for the promise to resolve.

```
doSomething()
{
    Promise.resolve()
        .then(() => {
            // do something.
        })
        .catch(reason => {
            this.logger.error(reason);
        });
}
```

Getting this error:

```
(node:2072) Warning: a promise was created in a handler at internal/timers.js:439:21 but was not returned from it, see http://. goo.gl/rRqMUw
    at Function.Promise.cast (.../node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:225:13)
```

Comment: It's not an error, it's a warning. You may ignore it.

Comment: I refer to this as a "fire and forget" asynchronous operation that you're not informing the caller about.  There are certainly some legit use cases for these (though, not super common).  Nothing wrong with it in the proper circumstance.  Just ignore the warning. The warning is probably there because 98-99% of the time this is a coding mistake.

Comment: I understand that, but the question is how to get rid of the warning. Thousands of such warning would make it hard to identify legit errors/warnings

Comment: Try/catch in the caller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just return something from the Promise callback where you are creating the `fire and forget` promise.

I'm guessing that handler is `doSomething`

```
doSomething()
{
    Promise.resolve()
    .then(() => {
        // do something.
    })
    .catch(reason => {
        this.logger.error(reason);
    });

    return null //or anything else that's sensible
}
```

Note: We usually ignore the error message, but sometimes they contain valuable information. In your error there's a link http://. goo.gl/rRqMUw that explains exactly this problem:d